# JSON encode into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, encode

I'm trying to grab a value from json and place it into my controller and having some issue.

I'm looking to have the membership value 8 put into $scope.value = data.membership;

JS. Service call

```
.service('getMembership', function ($http, SERVER_URL) {
        return {
            getMembership: function (userid) {
                var url = SERVER_URL + "services/getMembership.php?userid=" + userid;
                return $http.get(url);
            }

        };
    })
```

The php will return the following, which in turn will be returned by javascript.

```
{"membership":"8"}
```

Now I'm trying to add this in my controller and call it out into a chart in $scope.value.

```
    .controller('AwardCtrl', function ($scope, $interval, getMembership) {
      var userId = 1;
      getMembership.getMembership(userId).success(function(data) { 
        $scope.value = data.membership;

        $scope.options1 = {
        animate : { enabled: true, duration: 1500, ease: 'bounce' },
         readOnly: true,
          size: 200,
          max: 30,
          subText: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'DAYS LEFT',
            color: '#f2f2f2;',
            font: 'auto'
          },
          trackWidth: 40,
          barWidth: 25,
          trackColor: '#e6e6e6',
          barColor: '#81d8cf',
          dynamicOptions: true
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will return a string, but does the javascript $http.get convert this to a JSON object automatically? If not, you can use

```
var actualobject = JSON.parse(data);
$scope.value = actualobject.membership;
```

to convert it. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I'd consider using MDN as a better resource for Javascript Docs - [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)  - see [this explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: You could use JSON.parse inside the success function, on the data parameter. What you've used above is parsing the angular promise.